# How to Test Custom Hook with react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, react-hooks-testing-library

I tried using react-hooks-testing-library but it dosn't seem how handle hooks that use useContext.

```html
import React,{useContext} from 'react'
import {AuthContextData} from '../../AuthContext/AuthContext'
const useAuthContext = () => {
    const {authState} = useContext(AuthContextData) 
    const {isAuth,token,userId,userData} = authState
    return {isAuth,token,userId,userData}
  }
  export default useAuthContext
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing a custom hook with renderHook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442450/testing-a-custom-hook-with-renderhook)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap your hook in a context provider:

```
let authContext
renderHook(() => (authContext = useAuthContext()), {
  wrapper: ({ children }) => (
    <AuthContextData.Provider value={/* Your value */}>
      {children}
    <AuthContextData.Provider>
  )
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have a component where you call the useContext(context) hook to get a key isLoading that should be false or true.

If you want to test useContext in a component you could test it as follow:

```
const context = jest.spyOn(React, 'useContext');
```

if each test in the same file need to have different context values, then inside your test, you can mock the implementation like this:

```
context.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    return { isLoading: false };
  });
```

or outside the tests for all tests to have same context:

```
context.mockImplementation(() => {
    return { isLoading: false };
  });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Redux explicitly say [*Do not try to mock selector functions or the React-Redux hooks!*](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#guiding-principles)

Comment: But this is not redux, this is react. Although I believe the accepted answer is a best approach, this is valid as well.