# Testing a custom hook with renderHook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-hooks-testing-library

I want to test a custom hook which was implemented as an helping function for code reuse with other hooks. It's calling `useDispatch` and `useSelector` in its implementation, along with saving data in the session storage:

```
 export function useCustomHook(key, obj)
  {
    let myObject = {
      somefield: obj.someField
    };
    sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(myObject));
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    dispatch(actionCreator.addAction(key, myObject));
  }
```

And the test:

```
it('should have data in redux and session storage', () =>
{
  const obj = { 
    somefield: 'my val', 
  };
  renderHook(() => useCustomHook('some key', obj));
  let savedObj= JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('some key'));
  expect(savedObj.someField).toBe('my val');
  renderHook(() => 
  {
    console.log("INSIDE");
    let reduxObj = useSelector(state => state.vals);
    console.log("THE OBJECT: " );
    console.log(reduxObj);
    expect(reduxObj).toBe(2); //just to see if it fails the test - it's not
  });
})
```

No matter what I try, the test only arrives to the "INSIDE" console log and does not print the "THE OBJECT: " console log. The test itself still passes so it's like the `useSelector` somehow stops the rest of the renderHook execution.

I'm guessing it's related to the fact that the test doesn't have a store connected... What can be done to test redux in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to provide [a `wrapper` component](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/advanced-hooks#context) that add the redux `Provider` with a `store` to connect to:

```js
it('should have data in redux and session storage', () =>
{
  const obj = { 
    somefield: 'my val', 
  };

  const store = {} // create/mock a store
  const wrapper = ({ children }) => <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>

  renderHook(() => useCustomHook('some key', obj), { wrapper });
  let savedObj= JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('some key'));
  expect(savedObj.someField).toBe('my val');
  renderHook(() => {
    console.log("INSIDE");
    let reduxObj = useSelector(state => state.vals);
    console.log("THE OBJECT: " );
    console.log(reduxObj);
    expect(reduxObj).toBe(2); //just to see if it fails the test - it's not
  }, { wrapper });
})
```

Just as a side note, the `renderHook` is catching the errors, which is why you aren't seeing them in your test, if you had tried to access `result.current` it would have thrown, and you could have seen it represented in `result.error`, but the usage here of not returning a value from a custom hook to be asserted against is quite unusual.

This will likely also cause you issues by having the assertion inside second `renderHook` call.  You'll probably want to either return the value from the hook and assert outside, or assert the updated value in the redux store instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple extension of the [documented redux `renderWithProviders` function](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#setting-up-a-reusable-test-render-function). This looks like:

```js
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import type { RenderOptions } from '@testing-library/react'
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import type { PreloadedState } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react';


export function renderHookWithProviders<
  Result,
  Props>(
    render: (initialProps: Props) => Result,
    {
      preloadedState = {},
      // Automatically create a store instance if no store was passed in
      store = configureStore({
        reducer: {
....
        },
        preloadedState
      }),
      ...renderOptions
    }: ExtendedRenderOptions = {}
  ) {
  function Wrapper({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>): JSX.Element {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
  }

  return { store, ...renderHook(render, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }) }
}
```

Notice the `render` method is replaced with `renderHook` from `@testing-library/react`. This can then be used simply in your tests:

```js
describe('useGetRelated', () => {
  test('Return related', () => {
    const { result } = renderHookWithProviders(() => useGetRelated(), {
      preloadedState: {
        //initial state of redux
      }
    });


  });
});
```

The [hooks testing library talk about this briefly as well](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/advanced-hooks). Though the solution there requires more boiler plate in each test, the redux advocated solution seems better IMO.